# Have I named this compound correctly using IUPAC naming conventions?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I think it is 3-[3-[2-[[(2R)-2-(3-chlorophenyl)-2-hydroxyethyl]amino]ethylamino]-R-phenyl]-4-Ar. But I'm not sure and would really appreciate some help

[image: Unidentified molecule]